# PowerShell Cmdlet "Protect-PGP" Object Not Found

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that will encrypt file using the Protect-PGP cmdlet.  The script has been working without issues through 2/19/2024.  On 2/20/2024 we took security updates on the server where the script is running.  The script is now getting the following error :

Protect-PGP : The term 'Protect-PGP' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Scripts\EncryptUploadSSMfiles - New.ps1:4 char:1

- Protect-PGP -FilePathPublic $PSScriptRoot\Keys\SSMHealthPGPKey.asc -F ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Protect-PGP:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

The command line is :

Protect-PGP -FilePathPublic $PSScriptRoot\Keys\SSMHealthPGPKey.asc -FolderPath $PSScriptRoot\InboundFiles -OutputFolderPath $PSScriptRoot\OutboundFiles

I have verified that the file path for the key file and folder paths for the inbound and outbound files are correct.

Any idea as to why I am now getting this error and if so, how can I resolve?

Thanks

I tried searching for this error and didn't get any hits.

Comment: Did you install and import the module that contains that function ?

Comment: I did not as I inherited the custom powershell script.  It was working until the 19th of February.  Is this an "add on" to powershell that needs to be installed?  If so, do you have instructions for where I can find the module and how to install it?

Comment: Just google for it. Looks like you want to install [this module](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSPGP)

Comment: Theo,  Thank You for the information and instructions.  I'm very new to powershell and have only just begun working with it.  Your information and instructions were very helpful and I was able to resolve the problem.